# Injecting CoroutineWorker using Hilt initiate Error

Tags: android, kotlin, worker, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject a coroutine worker using dagger hilt,

**gradle version**

```
def work_version = "2.7.0"
// Kotlin + coroutines
implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version")


implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0-alpha01'
// When using Kotlin.
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

it occurs error like this

```
com.example.exampleapp E/WM-WorkerFactory: Could not instantiate com.example.exampleapp.domain.worker.AppNetworkWorker
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.exampleapp.domain.worker.AppNetworkWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
```

Here is my code

**BaseApplication**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
            .build()
}
```

**AppNetworkWorker**

```
@HiltWorker
class AppNetworkWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val testRepository: TestRepository
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {


    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "In here android Network")
        }catch (e: Exception){
            return Result.retry()
        }
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**TestRepository**

```
class TestRepository @Inject constructor(

){
    fun justLog() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location: TestRepository")
    }
}
```

Add this provider to my app AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    tools:node="remove">
</provider>
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#remove-default

I made it referring to the document on the site above, but it continues to fail in the initiate part.

Comment: I assume you are actually using `hilt:1.0.0` and not `1.0.0-alpha01`, given that `@HiltWorker` was added in [Version 1.0.0-alpha03](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt#1.0.0-alpha03), correct?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes you are right. it was my mistake. 1.0.0-alpha01 to  Version 1.0.0-alpha03, it works. Thanks